# Unity / Vuforia Update Leaves Me With a Blank Runtime Screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I just updated my Vuforia and Unity.

Vuforia I'm now using the latest **4.0.105**

Unity I'm using **5.0.1f1**

But ever since I started tying to make projects in this it's been giving me errors. So I stripped down the app and I've got just the Camera and the Image Target. And all I get is a blank black screen.

The situation before this was I had my GUI elements along with the Camera and the ImageTarget and it gave me the blank screen again but with the GUI buttons intact.

It's probably got something to do with the Camera since the LogCat stops on the same.

Any ideas how I overcome this?

Here's my `LogCat`

```
04-29 14:58:26.400: I/ActivityManager(426): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.rjj.roads/.UnityPlayerNativeActivity} from pid 647
04-29 14:58:26.455: I/ActivityManager(426): Start proc com.rjj.roads for activity com.rjj.roads/.UnityPlayerNativeActivity: pid=4648 uid=10097 gids={50097, 3003}
04-29 14:58:26.525: D/dalvikvm(4648): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.rjj.roads-2/libmain.so 0x420e6e78
04-29 14:58:26.525: D/dalvikvm(4648): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.rjj.roads-2/libmain.so 0x420e6e78
04-29 14:58:26.535: I/Unity(4648): splash_mode = 0 (integer)
04-29 14:58:26.535: I/Unity(4648): hide_status_bar = True (bool)
04-29 14:58:26.535: I/Unity(4648): useObb = False (bool)
04-29 14:58:26.580: D/Unity(4648): surfaces: attach glview
04-29 14:58:26.590: I/Unity(4648): Choreographer available: Enabling VSYNC timing
04-29 14:58:26.590: I/Unity(4648): onResume
04-29 14:58:26.695: I/Unity(4648): windowFocusChanged: true
04-29 14:58:26.705: I/ActivityManager(426): Displayed com.rjj.roads/.UnityPlayerNativeActivity: +261ms
04-29 14:58:26.840: D/mali_winsys(4648): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
04-29 14:58:26.850: D/Unity(4648): GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_ARM_rgba8 GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_required_internalformat GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_KHR_debug GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_texture_3D GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_ARM_mali_program_binary 
04-29 14:58:26.905: W/libc(4648): pthread_create sched_setscheduler call failed: Operation not permitted
04-29 14:58:27.745: I/Unity(4648): Setting BehaviourComponentFactory
04-29 14:58:27.745: I/Unity(4648):  
04-29 14:58:27.745: I/Unity(4648): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
04-29 14:58:27.760: W/SensorService(426): sensor 00000002 already enabled in connection 0x775f09a0 (ignoring)
04-29 14:58:27.780: I/Unity(4648): Trackable Image1 lost
04-29 14:58:27.780: I/Unity(4648):  
04-29 14:58:27.780: I/Unity(4648): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
04-29 14:58:27.880: D/dalvikvm(4648): GC_CONCURRENT freed 314K, 11% free 3235K/3612K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 19ms
04-29 14:58:28.000: D/dalvikvm(4648): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.rjj.roads-2/libVuforia.so 0x420e6e78
04-29 14:58:28.005: D/dalvikvm(4648): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.rjj.roads-2/libVuforia.so 0x420e6e78
04-29 14:58:28.010: D/dalvikvm(4648): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.rjj.roads-2/libQCARWrapper.so 0x420e6e78
04-29 14:58:28.010: D/dalvikvm(4648): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.rjj.roads-2/libQCARWrapper.so 0x420e6e78
04-29 14:58:28.010: D/dalvikvm(4648): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.rjj.roads-2/libQCARWrapper.so 0x420e6e78, skipping init
04-29 14:58:28.010: D/dalvikvm(4648): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.rjj.roads-2/libQCARUnityPlayer.so 0x420e6e78
04-29 14:58:28.010: D/dalvikvm(4648): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.rjj.roads-2/libQCARUnityPlayer.so 0x420e6e78
04-29 14:58:28.010: D/dalvikvm(4648): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.rjj.roads-2/libQCARUnityPlayer.so 0x420e6e78, skipping init
04-29 14:58:28.115: D/dalvikvm(4648): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.rjj.roads-2/libQCARWrapper.so 0x420e6e78
04-29 14:58:28.115: D/dalvikvm(4648): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.rjj.roads-2/libQCARWrapper.so' already loaded in same CL 0x420e6e78
04-29 14:58:28.115: D/QCAR(4648): Setting Unity version 5.0.1
04-29 14:58:28.115: D/QCAR(4648): QCAR Extension version 4.0.105
04-29 14:58:28.125: D/QCAR(4648): Initializing Vuforia...
04-29 14:58:28.130: I/AR(4648): QCAR has been initialized successfully
04-29 14:58:28.130: I/AR(4648): QCAR SDK version 4.0.105
04-29 14:58:28.185: D/dalvikvm(4648): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 308K, 11% free 3261K/3632K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
04-29 14:58:28.185: I/dalvikvm-heap(4648): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.557MB for 329009-byte allocation
04-29 14:58:28.190: D/dalvikvm(4648): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 10% free 3582K/3956K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
04-29 14:58:28.210: I/dalvikvm(4648): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
04-29 14:58:28.210: I/dalvikvm(4648): Total arena pages for JIT: 12
04-29 14:58:28.210: I/dalvikvm(4648): Total arena pages for JIT: 13
04-29 14:58:28.210: I/dalvikvm(4648): Total arena pages for JIT: 14
04-29 14:58:28.210: I/dalvikvm(4648): Total arena pages for JIT: 15
04-29 14:58:28.210: I/dalvikvm(4648): Total arena pages for JIT: 16
04-29 14:58:28.210: I/dalvikvm(4648): Total arena pages for JIT: 17
04-29 14:58:28.220: I/dalvikvm(4648): Total arena pages for JIT: 18
04-29 14:58:28.245: I/Unity(4648): QCAR initialization successful
04-29 14:58:28.245: I/Unity(4648):  
04-29 14:58:28.245: I/Unity(4648): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
04-29 14:58:28.280: D/QCAR(4648): trackerManagerInitTracker
04-29 14:58:28.285: D/QCAR(4648): trackerManagerInitTracker
04-29 14:58:28.335: I/Unity(4648): SetHint
04-29 14:58:28.335: I/Unity(4648):  
04-29 14:58:28.335: I/Unity(4648): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
04-29 14:58:28.340: I/Unity(4648): SetHint
04-29 14:58:28.340: I/Unity(4648):  
04-29 14:58:28.340: I/Unity(4648): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
04-29 14:58:28.340: I/Unity(4648): SetHint
04-29 14:58:28.340: I/Unity(4648):  
04-29 14:58:28.340: I/Unity(4648): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
04-29 14:58:28.350: D/QCAR(4648): dataSetExists
04-29 14:58:28.455: D/QCAR(4648): objectTrackerCreateDataSet
04-29 14:58:28.455: I/AR(4648): ObjectTracker: Successfully created dataset
04-29 14:58:28.455: D/QCAR(4648): Successfully created data set.
04-29 14:58:28.460: D/QCAR(4648): dataSetLoad
04-29 14:58:28.475: D/dalvikvm(4648): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 520K, 16% free 3425K/4036K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
04-29 14:58:28.645: D/QCAR(4648): dataSetGetNumTrackableType
04-29 14:58:28.645: D/QCAR(4648): dataSetGetTrackablesOfType
04-29 14:58:28.650: D/QCAR(4648): dataSetGetTrackableName
04-29 14:58:28.655: D/QCAR(4648): objectTargetGetSize
04-29 14:58:28.660: D/QCAR(4648): imageTargetGetNumVirtualButtons
04-29 14:58:28.660: D/QCAR(4648): dataSetGetNumTrackableType
04-29 14:58:28.660: D/QCAR(4648): dataSetGetNumTrackableType
04-29 14:58:28.685: D/QCAR(4648): objectTargetSetSize
04-29 14:58:28.695: I/Unity(4648): Found Trackable named Image1 with id 1
04-29 14:58:28.695: I/Unity(4648):  
04-29 14:58:28.695: I/Unity(4648): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
04-29 14:58:28.700: D/QCAR(4648): objectTrackerActivateDataSet
04-29 14:58:28.705: I/Unity(4648): StartQCAR
04-29 14:58:28.705: I/Unity(4648):  
04-29 14:58:28.705: I/Unity(4648): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
04-29 14:58:28.715: D/QCAR(4648): cameraDeviceInitCamera
04-29 14:58:28.725: I/AwesomePlayer(122): setDataSource_l(URL suppressed)
04-29 14:58:28.735: I/AwesomePlayer(122): setDataSource_l(URL suppressed)
04-29 14:58:28.745: I/Camera2ClientBase(122): Camera 0: Opened
04-29 14:58:28.745: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): >>> I'm Samsung's CameraHAL_2(ID:0) <<<
04-29 14:58:28.745: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): g_cam2_device : 0x00000000
04-29 14:58:28.745: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): (ExynosCameraHWInterface2): ENTER
04-29 14:58:28.860: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): (ExynosCameraHWInterface2): EXIT
04-29 14:58:28.920: D/dalvikvm(4648): GC_CONCURRENT freed 497K, 15% free 3430K/4036K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 15ms
04-29 14:58:28.935: D/QCAR(4648): cameraDeviceGetVideoMode
04-29 14:58:28.955: I/Unity(4648): Using default scene scale for device: 1
04-29 14:58:28.955: I/Unity(4648):  
04-29 14:58:28.955: I/Unity(4648): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
04-29 14:58:28.955: D/QCAR(4648): cameraDeviceSelectVideoMode
04-29 14:58:28.980: D/QCAR(4648): cameraDeviceStartCamera
04-29 14:58:28.990: D/dalvikvm(4648): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 372K, 16% free 3419K/4036K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
04-29 14:58:28.990: I/dalvikvm-heap(4648): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.841MB for 464912-byte allocation
04-29 14:58:29.000: D/dalvikvm(4648): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 14% free 3873K/4492K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
04-29 14:58:29.010: D/dalvikvm(4648): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 14% free 3873K/4492K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 11ms
04-29 14:58:29.010: D/dalvikvm(4648): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
04-29 14:58:29.010: I/dalvikvm-heap(4648): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.285MB for 464912-byte allocation
04-29 14:58:29.020: D/dalvikvm(4648): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 13% free 4327K/4948K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
04-29 14:58:29.035: D/dalvikvm(4648): GC_EXPLICIT freed 72K, 15% free 4255K/4948K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 15ms
04-29 14:58:29.035: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): (allocateStream): stream width(640) height(480) format(22)
04-29 14:58:29.040: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): (registerStreamBuffers): stream_id(0), num_buff(9), handle(b720ef70) 
04-29 14:58:29.045: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): (allocateStream): stream width(2560) height(1920) format(21)
04-29 14:58:29.085: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): (registerStreamBuffers): stream_id(4), num_buff(6), handle(b72296f0) 
04-29 14:58:29.085: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): (allocateStream): stream width(640) height(480) format(11)
04-29 14:58:29.095: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): (registerStreamBuffers): stream_id(2), num_buff(13), handle(b722cdd8) 
04-29 14:58:29.095: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): (allocateStream): stream width(2560) height(1920) format(ffffffff)
04-29 14:58:29.095: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): (allocateStream): jpeg stream exists
04-29 14:58:29.095: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): START stream thread 1 release 1869
04-29 14:58:29.105: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): END   stream thread 1 release 1874
04-29 14:58:29.115: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): (registerStreamBuffers): stream_id(5), num_buff(11), handle(b7231138) 
04-29 14:58:29.120: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): (allocateReprocessStreamFromStream): output_stream_id(5)
04-29 14:58:29.155: D/QCAR(4648): markerTrackerStart
04-29 14:58:29.155: D/QCAR(4648): objectTrackerStart
04-29 14:58:29.185: D/QCAR(4648): cameraDeviceGetVideoMode
04-29 14:58:29.280: D/ExynosCameraHAL2(122): ### Applying AF Mode change(Mode 2) 
04-29 14:58:29.360: I/Unity(4648): Trackable Image1 lost
04-29 14:58:29.360: I/Unity(4648):  
04-29 14:58:29.360: I/Unity(4648): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
04-29 14:58:29.370: D/QCAR(4648): cameraDeviceGetVideoMode
04-29 14:58:37.275: D/dalvikvm(4648): GC_CONCURRENT freed 459K, 14% free 4281K/4940K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 24ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a Unity problem, that wasn't allowing us to extend Projects into the Android devices. This was fixed with the Unity patch fix **Unity 5.0.1p3**

If anyone else comes across the same problem, a lot of questions here address that it could be because of an older version or beta version of Unity or Vuforia, so update/downgrade accordingly.

Hope this helps.